# jQuery - checking whether element exists - which way is best?

Tags: jquery, validation, element

I have an element called link which I need to check.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
// routine
if ( link.length == 1 && !link.is( ".toggle_popover" ) ) {
    self.panelTrans();
    }
```

I'm curious regarding my check for *link*

I have tried the following:

```
if (link) ... 
if (!link)...
if (link.length == 1) ...
if (link.length != 0) ...
```

The problem is *link* can also be an empty object = [], in which case I don't want my routine to fire.

Which way is best to do this? Right now I'm sticking with *link.length == 1*

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE**

**link** is the following:

```
var link = $( self.findClosestLink(event.target) )

findClosestLink: function (ele) {
      var self = this;
      while (ele){
          if (ele.nodeName.toLowerCase() == "a"){
              break;
              }
           ele = ele.parentNode;
           }
      return ele;
      }
```

It's taken from the jQuery Mobile script and checks when the user clicks on screen if there is a parent link element. I'm using this to fire my own routine along JQM and want to make sure I'm not triggering any wasted function call. That's why I'm checking for link. On Firebug I sometimes ended up with the function being triggered on an empty object [], which I do not want it to fire on.

Therefore my question on how to check for *link*

Comment: how are you setting `link`?  Your code suggests that it's a jQuery object, not an element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think that the best way is (i suppose you are speaking of a jQuery object)

```
var link = $('#link');

link.length === 1
```

with an added `=` so there is no type coercion. If you use an `id` selector this is perfect as the selector returns only one element (this of course implies that your ids are unique on your page).
if you must check if at least one element exist in a collection (You use a `class` selector) of course use

```
collection.length > 0
```

Comment: Thanks! Right now, I think this works best. Need to try some more.

Answer (score 1):

If `link` is a jQuery object, just use:

```
if (link.length)
```

There's no need for an explicit comparison unless you want to be sure that there's *exactly* one matching element.

The value of `.length` will either be zero, which when used as a boolean evaluates to false, or positive, evaluating to true.

Comment: Thanks but I think I'm going with Nicolas solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( link.length)
{
  // element exist
}
```

Assumuming link is a jquery object

If link is an id of an element,

```
 if($("#link").length)
 {
   // element exist
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#link').length){
//its available
}
```

This is the proper way. It's also described on the jQuery homepage. It's the fastest way to check if the element is available !